Error term of Fourier series for fractional part
In a paper of HeathBown(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X83900446),P.245, there is a Fourier expension of fractional part
$$\{x\}=\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^H\frac{\sin 2\pi nx}{\pi n}+O\big(g(x,H)\big),$$
where
$$g(x,H)=\min\big(1,(H||x||)^{-1}\big)=\sum_{h=-\infty}^{\infty}a_h e(xh),$$
in which $||x||=\min_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|x-n|$, $e(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$ and
$a_h\ll\min\big(\frac{\log(2H)}{H},\frac{1}{|h|},\frac{H}{|h|^2}\big)$.
For the estimate of $a_h$, I can get that
$$a_h=2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\min\big(1,(Hx)^{-1}\big)e(-xh)dx\ll \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\min\big(1,(Hx)^{-1}\big)dx\ll H^{-1}\log(2H);$$
and
$$a_h=\frac{1}{\pi i h} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\min\big(1,(Hx)^{-1}\big)d(e(-xh))\ll \frac{1}{|h|}.$$
I have no idea about the last one. How can I get
$$a_h\ll \frac{H}{|h|^2}?$$
